# Finding occurrence of first string in an array in js

Tags: javascript

Suppose I am given an array

```
myArray=[10,true,1.5,'Asia', 20, 'rat'];
```

Now which function should I use to get the index of the first occurrence of a string in array?

Comment: use filter function

Comment: `findIndex` would be one of the option...

Comment: filter function with`typeof`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

```js
const result = [10,true,1.5,'Asia', 20, 'rat'].findIndex(item => typeof item === "string");
console.log(result);
```

> The findIndex() method returns the **index of the first element** in the array that satisfies the provided testing function.
>
> Source: [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find the first index of the string then [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) would be one of the best options.

```js
const myArray = [10, true, 1.5, "Asia", 20, "rat"];
const index = myArray.findIndex((s) => typeof s === "string");
console.log(index);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `findIndex`

```js
const myArray=[10,true,1.5,'Asia', 20, 'rat'];

const index = myArray.findIndex( ( el ) => {
    return typeof el === 'string';
} );

console.log('Answer : ', index);
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally you can use findIndex, but you can also use normal `for..` loop and `break`

```js
let myArray = [10, true, 1.5, 'Asia', 20, 'rat'];

let ind = -1;
for (let x = 0; x < myArray.length; x++) {
  if (typeof myArray[x] === 'string') {
    ind = x;
    break;
  }
}

console.log(ind)
```

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, here's the [Mozilla's specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) of the `Array.prototype.filter()` method.